# what does mean by thread suspended in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, locking, watchdog, suspend

Today, i find a android system server watch dog. whats my wonder is what's the mean by thread suspended. cpu interrupt ? condition ? or sth other?

```
"android.bg" prio=5 tid=11 Suspended
   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c07ee0 self=0xb9316130
   | sysTid=851 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xa1a5b930
   | state=S schedstat=( 184530394556 9432479551235 584981 ) utm=8091 stm=10362 core=0 HZ=100
   | stack=0xa1959000-0xa195b000 stackSize=1038KB
   | held mutexes=
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:315)
   at com.android.server.power.PowerManagerService.findWakeLockIndexLocked(PowerManagerService.java:1136)
   at com.android.server.power.PowerManagerService.acquireWakeLockInternal(PowerManagerService.java:972)
   - locked <0x0745d2ea> (a java.lang.Object)
   at com.android.server.power.PowerManagerService.-wrap10(PowerManagerService.java:-1)
   at com.android.server.power.PowerManagerService$BinderService.acquireWakeLock(PowerManagerService.java:3502)
   at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquireLocked(PowerManager.java:1212)
   at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire(PowerManager.java:1180)
   - locked <0x065001ee> (a android.os.Binder)
   at com.android.server.LocationManagerService$Receiver.incrementPendingBroadcastsLocked(LocationManagerService.java:1157)
   at com.android.server.LocationManagerService$Receiver.callLocationChangedLocked(LocationManagerService.java:1066)
   - locked <0x0b0fcda8> (a com.android.server.LocationManagerService$Receiver)
   at com.android.server.LocationManagerService.handleLocationChangedLocked(LocationManagerService.java:2546)
   at com.android.server.LocationManagerService.handleLocationChanged(LocationManagerService.java:2637)
   - locked <0x0b5df02c> (a java.lang.Object)
   at com.android.server.LocationManagerService.-wrap4(LocationManagerService.java:-1)
   at com.android.server.LocationManagerService$LocationWorkerHandler.handleMessage(LocationManagerService.java:2606)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)



"main" prio=5 tid=1 Blocked
   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x74356b50 self=0xb83b5ba8
   | sysTid=823 nice=-2 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f45de4
   | state=S schedstat=( 35078771700 49538712267 54500 ) utm=1765 stm=1742 core=1 HZ=100
   | stack=0xbe411000-0xbe413000 stackSize=8MB
   | held mutexes=
   at com.android.server.LocationManagerService.locationCallbackFinished(LocationManagerService.java:1185)
   - waiting to lock <0x0b5df02c> (a java.lang.Object) held by thread 11
   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:307)
```

as you can see, main thread was blocked by android.bg with lock 0x0b5df02c. but i don't understand why android.bg thread's state is suspended.

Comment: ' 1427:  851,(  102,  1, 0x000002a3c000,  1, 0, 24),(00, 04),(    0ns , 0, 0),(15170.821608,   31us,   13ms,   81us,   13ms),  13ms
 1428:  851,(  102,  1, 0x000002a3c000,  1, 0, 24),(00, 04),(    0ns , 0, 0),(15170.821608,   31us,   13ms,   81us,   13ms),  13ms'

Comment: root      102   2     0      0     2  20    0     0     0     fg  dpmgr_wait 00000000 S     display_check_a